# Ошибка после билда

Tags: unity3d, webpack

Создал игру на unity и хотел залить на Яндекс игры, но после билда решил потестить. Скачал xampp. Запустил и вылезла ошибка. Не знаю как исправить. Помогите добрые люди пожалуйста.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоле пишет вот такую непонятную для меня штуку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Умоляю! Добрые люди! Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если на игру не влияет и всё работает то забей, а вообще попробуй залить не только на яндекс игры, может дело не в игре - а в самих яндекс играх

пока-что инфы мало, нажми на кнопку Swich DevTools to Russian, и посмотри что будет писать ошибка

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос